# HTMLAudioElement wont mute properly in Safari on iPod Touch (5.0.1)

Tags: javascript, ios, html5-audio

**Problem:** I am having issues toggling the muted property on an html5 audio tag.

**Platform:** Only on iPod Touch (**Safari**) [**iOS** 5.0.1]. Works fine in Chrome.

```
// This code resides in my click binding.
var audios = document.getElementsByTagName('audio')[0];
console.log(audios.muted); // returns false by default
if(audios.muted == true){
  audios.muted = false;
}
else{
  audios.muted = true;
}
```

In chrome, the console.log will toggle true/false, however on the iPod, it will always stay false.

Comment: I just looked at the docs and found that on the desktop you can set the volume property,however, on mobile it says "On iOS devices, the audio level is always under the user’s physical control. The volume property is not settable
in JavaScript. Reading the volume property always returns 1.". This makes no sense to me why you can't mute or adjust the volume of an audio element.

Comment: You might be able to work around the problem using the audio API. I'm no expert on the complete capabilities and limitations, but I managed to cobble together some code that played a simple tone and then JS could be used to change the volume or more specifically the "gain". User interaction was necessary to create the tone and start playing, but after that I had full control over the sound level, letting me use it as a very simple audio alert for certain events.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/safari/documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/Using_HTML5_Audio_Video/Using_HTML5_Audio_Video.pdf):

> On iOS devices, the audio level is always under the user’s physical control. The volume property is not settable in JavaScript. Reading the volume property always returns 1.

Looks like you have to use the hardware switch. It seems that on an iPhone the volume switch will not affect Safaris volume (defaults to the ringer volume, unless a sound a sound is playing then you can adjust Safaris volume), whereas, on the iPod, the volume switch does.

Hopefully this helps someone else.

Comment: Just hit this same problem: anyone have suggestions on how to get the audio to pause or stop or anything?

Comment: My fix for this is to toggle play/pause on mute button click on mobile devices. I know, we're not supposed to sniff but sometimes it is the only solution. 
F**king iOS… haha

Answer (score 0):

As of Safari 16 they still don't allow you to change the volume through javascript but you can mute the audio. You can easily mute by setting `muted` to `true` on the audio object.

```js
const audio = new Audio();
audio.muted = true // mutes audio
audio.muted = false // unmutes audio
```

Comment: This doesn't work on iOS Safari 16 for me

Comment: Are you setting muted on the right audio object?